# Amazon EC2 Tomcat7 instance unable to access MySQL db on same system

Tags: mysql, linux, security, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I think I've seen a variety of similar posts on this topic, but am still unable to resolve my issue, so I figured I'd post with my specifics.

I have an Amazon AWS Linux EC2 instance running Tomcat7 web server.  On the same machine I am also running a MySQL5 server, but I am unable to get the Tomcat app to talk to the MySQL database.

My Java app on tomcat tries to connect to MySQL by reading from a properties file:

```
jdbc.mysql.host.path=jdbc:mysql://localhost/  
jdbc.mysql.schema=prod  
jdbc.mysql.username=root  
jdbc.mysql.password=<password>
```

I am accessing the app from another system via web browser, but when the app tries to connect to the database I get the following error in catalina.out:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I'm pretty sure the issue has to do with permissions and communication between Tomcat and MySQL, because **I've written a simple java program utilizing the same code to read the same properties file, and the connection is made successfully**.

**Here are some things I have attempted to remedy the issue:**

- change the owner of the properties file (currently owned by 'Tomcat')
- ensured that user 'root' has been granted all privileges in MySQL
- ensured that port 3306 (MySQL default port) is accessible by my test server
- updated iptables made various modifications to /etc/my.cnf file
  (tried to bind ip, but that didn't work)

I have a hunch that the issue may be related to the fact that I am trying to access the MySQL database using user 'root'.  Even though I'm accessing it via localhost, the system may not support this because MySQL treats this as access from a separate host and (maybe?) root access from other hosts isn't allowed?

Any suggestions on things to try would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: This is not a firewall issue. If it was, you would see a different error. Instead this is an issue with your user/password combination within mysql.

Comment: I don't see how that could be the case if my stand-alone Java program utilizes the same code and properties file to get the username and password

Comment: Check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-connecting.html.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue was a combination of things.
Here are some items to consider that ultimately fixed it for me:
  - making sure you were accessing the correct app via browser (I was using ROOT app, but trying to connect to another one)
  - making sure a user exists in MySQL using 'Create User ....'
  - making sure all privileges are granted on **the database in question**, for some reason granting all privileges on *.* wasn't working for me